# Django model joining a one to many relationship for displaying in a template

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-templates, left-join

Not sure what the best way to describe the problem is. I have 2 tables contact and attribute. The contact table has 1 entry per person and the attribute table has 0, 1, or many entries per person. They are joined currently with a "fake" foreign key that isn't really a foreign key. If I need to add the foreign key I will it is not a big deal just dealing with old data and there was no foreign key originally. So the tables are laid out as follows:

contact:

```
class contact(models.Model):
    contactId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='contactId')
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, db_column='firstName')
    middleName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, db_column='middleName')
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, db_column='lastName')
```

attribute:

```
class attribute(models.Model):
    attributeId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='attributeId')
    contactId = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, null=True, db_column='contactId')
    attributeValue = models.TextField(null=True, db_column='attributeValue')
```

So I have correctly set up the Django models to represent these tables. Now what I need to accomplish is a view and template to loop over these tables such that it generates an xml doc in the following format:

```
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <contactId></contactId>
        <firstName></firstName>
        <lastName></lastName>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <attributeId></attributeId>
                <attributeValue></attributeValue>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

So there would be a listing of all contacts and all of the attributes associated with each contact.

I am sure there is a simple way to accomplish this. In other languages I would simple write two looping queries to loop over the contact and then loop over the attributes for each contact. However the company I work for is migrating to a new platform and want the new application written in django/python both of which I am still trying to learn.

Any help that anyone can provide is appreciated.

Comment: What do your models look like? Is there any reason not to define `attribute.contactId` as a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: The only reason it doesn't have a foreign key set is because it is an older database model. Nothing against foreign keys the company has just never them. I added the actual models in the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you've set up your django models to use your current database setup, I'd do the following if I didn't have a foreign key set up.

```
contacts = Contact.objects.all()

for contact in contacts:
    contact.attributes = Attribute.objects.filter(contactId=contact.pk) 


return render_to_response("mytemplate.html", {'contacts': contacts })
```

Alternately, save some queries;

```
attributes_map = dict( 
    [(attribute.contactId, attribute) for attribute in \
        Attribute.objects.filter(contactId__in=[contact.pk for contact in contacts])]
    )

for contact in contacts:
    contact.attributes = attributes_map.get(contact.pk)

return render_to_response("mytemplate.html", {'contacts': contacts })
```

Template

```
<contacts>
{% for contact in contacts %}
    <contact>
        <contactId>{{ contact.pk }}</contactId>
        <firstName>{{ contact.firstName }}</firstName>
        <lastName>{{ contact.lastName }}</lastName>

        {% if contact.attributes %}
            <attributes>
            {% for attribute in contact.attributes %}
                <attribute>
                    <attributeId>{{ attribute.pk }}</attributeId>
                    <attributeValue>{{ attribute.attributeValue }}</attributeValue>
                </attribute>
            {% endfor %}
            </attributes>
        {% endif %}

    </contact>
{% endfor %}
</contacts>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly want I needed. I hadn't realized I could add properties to the queryset that had not originally been defined in the model's class. Is there another method that I should take if I add the foreign keys to the table?

Comment: Yes! Everything is just a python object -- it's a great concept to grasp. You can put random things on your request object, a form passed into a view you don't have control over, etc. Interestingly, I would still use my second method even if you had a foreign key -- the reason is that "backwards" relationships are not automatically queried so to save DB queries, I'd use the 2 step process.

Comment: If it were a situation where we had only one contact, there is a convenience method for reverse foreignkeys which is `fieldname_set`. Every model that has a foreign key pointing to it automatically gets an attribute, `fieldname_set` that you can query in the same manner as `filter`. e.g. `contact.attribute_set.all()` there are some quirks that you should check the docs for if you want to explore further

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are in legacy db hell.

As such, you will probably find it difficult to use standard django model stuff like ForeignKey, but you should still strive to keep code like that out of the view code.

So it would probably be better to define some methods on your contact class, something like...

```
def attributes(self):
    return Attribute.objects.filter(contactId=self.contactId)
```

then, you can use that in your templates.

```
<attributes>
    {% for attribute in contact.attributes.all %}
        <attribute>
            ...
        </attribute>
    {% endfor %}
</attribute>
```

Though, contact.attributes.all in a template might not be ideal(nailing the relationship in the template). but it would be simple to add into your view to stuff something into the context.

Answer (score 0):

Yuji's answer is a lot like Nick Johnson's prefetch_refprops for App Engine:
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine

I found a way to optimize this code:

```
attributes_map = dict( 
    [(attribute.contactId, attribute) for attribute in \
        Attribute.objects.filter(contactId__in=[contact.pk for contact in contacts])]
    )
```

Replace it with:

```
attributes_map = dict(Attribute.objects
    .filter(contactId__in=set([contact.pk for contact in contacts]))
    .values_list('contactId', 'attribute'))
```

This substitution saves time in the query by:

- compacting the list of keys into a set(), and
- retrieving only the two fields used by the dict().

It also takes advantage of the fact that .values_list() returns the list of tuples expected by dict(), but this only works if the first field (i.e., 'contactId') is unique.

To extend this solution for multiple foreign keys, create a map for each key field using the code above.  Then, inside of this loop:

```
for contact in contacts:
    contact.attributes = attributes_map.get(contact.pk)
```

add a line for each foreign key.  For example,

```
attributes_map = dict(Attribute.objects
    .filter(contactId__in=set([contact.pk for contact in contacts]))
    .values_list('contactId', 'attribute'))
names_map = dict(Name.objects
    .filter(nameId__in=set([contact.nameId for contact in contacts]))
    .values_list('nameId', 'name'))

for contact in contacts:
    contact.attributes = attributes_map.get(contact.pk)
    contact.name = names_map.get(contact.nameId)
```

If you've ever had a template generate lots of extra SQL calls for each row of a result set (in order to look up each foreign key's value), this approach will make a huge savings by pre-loading all the data before sending it to the template.